# How to ingore the displayed header by using # in markdown?

Tags: hash, markdown, readme

I'm writing a readme.md file, I wanted it to be like this:

```
#create a new env
$some code
$code
```

But in markdown, the first line will become very big and displayed as a header, like this:
[image]

I just want it to be displayed as a normal format, any suggestions?

Comment: Why not include it in a code block, like you did in the question above?

Comment: You're right, it can be solved by adding ```, thanks